# translate this code in phpmyadmin to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, average

i want to translate this code in phpmyadmin to laravel

```
SELECT AVG(valeur_5), id_client, nom_propriete, prenom_propreite, nom_entreprise, type_utilisatuer
FROM cliets c
         INNER JOIN evaluations e on c.id = e.id_client
         INNER JOIN users u on u.id = c.id_user
         INNER JOIN propreites p on p.id_user = u.id
GROUP BY id_client
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed raw SQL into your program, just wrap it in a `DB::select`.

`DB::select("SELECT AVG(valeur_5), id_client, nom_propriete, prenom_propreite, nom_entreprise, type_utilisatuer FROM cliets c INNER JOIN evaluations e on c.id = e.id_client INNER JOIN users u on u.id = c.id_user INNER JOIN propreites p on p.id_user = u.id GROUP BY id_client")`

Alternatively, you can rewrite it with the [Eloquent query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries).

Comment: i have SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Comment: $orders = DB::table('clients')
          ->join('evaluations','evaluations.id_herfi','clients.id')
          ->join('users','users.id','hrayfis.id_user')
          ->join('propreites','propreites.id_user','users.id')
                ->select(
                 DB::raw('avg(valeur_5)','propreites.nom_propriete '))
                ->groupBy('cleints.id')->get();

Comment: i tread this i have error now in code html whene i send $orders to list in html ihave this code : Undefined property: stdClass::$nom_propriete

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, it means `DB::select` is working, you've got errors with either your sql or mysql user access rights.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
      $orders = DB::table('hrayfis')
      ->join('evaluations','evaluations.id_herfi','hrayfis.id')
      ->join('users','users.id','hrayfis.id_user')
      ->join('propreites','propreites.id_user','users.id')
            ->select(
             DB::raw('avg(valeur_5)','propreites.nom_propriete '))
            ->groupBy('hrayfis.id')->get();
```

Comment: i tread this i have error now in code html whene i send $orders to list in html